# IntelliJ IDEA 13: new Scala SBT project hasn't src directory structure generated

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, intellij-13

I followed the getting start video on Jetbrains website to setup IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 Community Edition to work with Scala. Scala plugin v0.36.431 had been installed. While I created a new Scala SBT project with wizard, there was no `src/` directory structure generated in the project. Only two sbt files were generated:

```
scala-course/
├── build.sbt
└── project
    └── plugins.sbt
```

From the video and other document I know that there should be a `src/` directory structure, including `src/main/scala`, `src/test/scala`, etc. sbt uses the same directory structure as Maven for source files by default.

I can create those folders manually and mark it as source root. However it is trivial. So my question is: Why IntelliJ IDEA new project wizard doesn't generate the directory structure as said in document? Was I doing something wrong? I checked the preferences and couldn't find anything that seems related.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to lpiepiora, with his [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23722653/639107) I find out the reason.

Because my sbt is newly installed, there is nothing in `~/.ivy2/cache/` and `~/.sbt/boot/`. sbt needed to download required dependencies from repositories on network. It happened that my proxy to internet had something wrong, download stuck.

And also need to notice that, if quit IntelliJ IDEA when sbt is running in background, the next time you'll get error of waiting for some lock file. Have to remove the lock file on filesystem and restart IntelliJ IDEA again.

After fixed the network problem, everything work as promised. It requires several minutes, depends on network speed, to download required jar files. After finished, the `src/` directory structure is created.

Answer (score 53):

Normally it should create these folders automatically. It may take a while though - it takes couple of seconds in my case.

When creating project make sure you have selected *Scala -> SBT*, then proceed with the wizard.

Once the *Finish* is clicked, the project will be loaded. **This part takes couple of seconds, and I can see no `src/main/scala` nor `src/test/scala` generated until it's done**. Observe the bottom of the screen to see when it's done.

[image: Loading Process]

Once the process is finished, you'll see the folders.

[image: Loaded Done]

If that's not the case, check the settings. You should have the *Create directories for empty content roots automatically* checked. You may want to check *Use auto-import* to automatically propagate changes in the `build.sbt`.

[image: Settings]

After changing the settings (if the change is required) you may need to refresh the project, as seen in picture below.

[image: Refresh Settings]

Comment: Thank you.  In my case it took 5 MINUTES.  There were 2 processes running, (see activity at the bottom right), one was updating SBT, the other was creating indices.  After SBT was done, the directories appeared.

Answer (score 10):

This can also happen if you do not have a JDK selected. For some reason you no longer get the option to select an SDK so you must make sure you have configured this before hand. To fix this do the following:

```
From the welcome screen, go to 
Configure -> Project defaults -> Project structure and add the jdk.
```

Source:
[What's the reason for "Error:Cannot determine Java VM executable in selected JDK"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201365/whats-the-reason-for-errorcannot-determine-java-vm-executable-in-selected-jdk)

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions in this thread but I had a java crash in the final phase in sbt with the configuration bellow and I think this info maybe useful:

The problem happened with IDEA 2016.2, sbt 0.13.8 (I tried later to import using 0.13.12 but the crash was the same), scala 2.11.8 and ubuntu 16.04.

The only way I could make it work was to use java 8 instead of 9.

```
error: error while loading package, Missing dependency 'object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror', required by /home/jbamaral/.sbt/boot   at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
... 
stack log here
...
[error] scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
```